# $f(x^2)=f(x)+f(-x)$

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function

Is there only one function (or class of functions) for which $f(x^2)=f(x)+f(-x)$? I know $\ln(1-x)$ fits the identity...
I tried finding $f(xy)$, hoping that it equals $f(x)+f(y)$ because then it would be a logarithm, to no avail.

Thanks

Edit, the domain of the function should be $(-1,1)$

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this.... i want the domain to be (-1, 1). Editing now

Comment: @markvs the range doesnt matter for this purpose, any function would do. Maybe I'm miss understanding your question. I just want to know if ln(1-t) is the only function for which that is true, if another function satisfy the domain and indenty, that's all i need to know

Comment: @markvs oh yes, dumb of me. The range should be a subset of the real numbers but no particular interval in mind

Comment: @VTand Thanks for this. Although the very existence of any not "nice" function is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many solutions. We need $f(0)=0$. From there, define $f(x)$ however you like for positive values of $x$. Finally, for $x<0$, let $f(x) = f(x^2) - f(-x)$.

Example: $$f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2 & x \ge 0 \\ x^4 - x^2 & x<0\end{cases}$$